# is there a keylogger in my phone

Tags: security

I have an Android phone accent a400 and I sent it to a repair store to change the broken screen.
After receiving the phone, I noticed that they did a reset to the phone and the internal memory doesn't appear in the file manager. Also the application SuperSU which was installed by default doesn't exist any more, so I installed ES file explorer and used it to verify that the system and racine folder still exist. Then I installed Framaroot after rooting the phone and the application SuperSU became visible.
Sometimes "the message was sent" popup alone when using the phone. How would I fix this?

Comment: Do a factory reset of the phone again, then re-root it.

Comment: The service center guys flashed a stock firmware( unrooting it) which is pretty safe. Since the device is unrooted there isn't a way for a malicious app to reside in `/system` , so a factory reset will get rid of your worries. And regarding that message sending, it could be carrier related or standard outgoing message after a factory reset. To be sure, you can just reflash the stock firmware.

Comment: Thank you all for all your answers
I am not sure but i read that doing a Hard reset dosen't remove installed keylogger and for flashing with stock ROM i dont know where to find the correct ROM to my phone which is Accent A400 and wich software to use but i think that solution will fix the problem .

Answer (score 1):

use this app to check pesent logging apps on your phone http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=17612559
if your phone is not a htc only one or two should show up, tombstones (crash dumps for kernel panics and such) and, flash Player (if installed) 
possibly google services would show up but that would be googles av scanner built into google services

for htc devices another would show up for htc usage logs

Comment: forgot the link  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=17612559

Comment: David thank you for your answer i have installed the application in the link and this is what i found

Loggers found

*/data/data/anr*
Mtk_traces.text
Native1.txt
Native1_1.txt 
.
.
And similair files
Sf_RTT
Traces.text
And others

*/data/data/tombstones*

*/data/system/dropbox*
Contains many text files
Sytem-Boot@a number.txt
Many files
System-app_anr@a number.txt
Event-log
Snet-gcore
Event-data
Data-app-crash

*app usage logs found
/data/system/usage stats
Google usage stats

Comment: Here is  other informations i found.Find adware log files

*Google analytics data found
*flurry data found
*mobclix data found
Admob data found

App scanners here what I found may be suspected

Ktcit

Hidden uis

Protps apk
Meditek.mtklogger
Com.android.dreams
Photo table
Com.meditek.lbs.em.mytabactivity
Eu.chainfire.supersu 
// it poped up after installing framaroot
And
Com.mtk.user2root //I didn't installed that

Comment: Sorry if the details are not well ordered

Comment: the data/data/anr Mtk_traces.text are normal as well as data/data/tombstones,  /data/system/dropbox, and /data/system/usage stats Google usage stats are all normal and created by android.  Google analytics is normal as some apps may use Google analytics, mobclix is a advertising network as well as the flurry data and they are for an apps that use ads, Com.android.dreams is a screen saver and should be harmless, Com.mtk.user2root is for frameroot (which you can uninstall after rooting), and Eu.chainfire.supersu is for superuser. for hidden uis Ktcit is for device servicing and Meditek.mtklogger

Comment: is for devices with MediaTek gps chips but it shouldn't send any of that info to external sources, i would recommend you turn it off though to save performance and ram http://teleread.com/smartphones/how-to-save-loads-of-memory-on-a-mediatek-device/ use this tutorial to turn it off